# Laptop internal HDD - What matters?

Tags: hard-drive

My old 500gig HDD just died, and I want to buy another one ASAP. SSD is out of the question since I'm short on cash. But I'm not knowledgable about HDDs, so can anyone tell me what all parameters actually matter in HDDs and what all are marketing gimmicks? RPM? Cache? Z-Heigh

Take a look at this: http://www.hgst.com/hard-drives/mobile-drives/7mm-thin-and-light-drives/travelstar-z5k500

My current one which failed was this : http://storage.toshiba.eu/cms/en/hdd/computing/product_detail.jsp?productid=340

I hope the fact that the HGST is 7mm and my current one is 9.5mm won't be an issue, else I'd have to buy a new casing as well.

Comment: shopping recomendations are off-topic here. if you re-write your comment in a way it fits our website field of action, your question will likely not be closed.

Comment: Not really on topic for here, but yes, you should be able to fit a 7mm drive into a bigger drive bay. There's shims available if you want/need a snugger fit. And HGST is basically owned by WD, but have a very good rep for reliability

Answer (score 2):

The hardware spec for HDD that matters (for users in general) are:

- Physical Size (yes we had purchased laptop HDD that doesn't fit into the client's laptop - not fun)
- HDD Capacity (how much storage you can / want to use)
- SATA/IDE connector (get the wrong one, and it won't fit) - IDE is older, SATA is the one for most (if not all) current laptops.
- Price - (for obvious reason)

Below are somewhat important but can easily be ignored for most users:

- RPM (which decides how fast the HDD spins and maybe how hot the HDD will run) - Most users can't see any difference between 5400 and 7200 RPM drives for the normal day to day usage.
- Cache (affect the HDD performance) - Again, very hard to notice unless you are using the HDD extensively and know exactly what you're doing with the HDD.

The rest of the details.. are an overkill information for most users, unless you really know what you're after and the information matters to your very specific need.
 Say you need an extremely quiet system because you are an audiophile and extremely sensitive to additional noise, so you wanted an extremely quiet HDD/System... - see what I mean? Very very specific/exotic need.